# Is there a way to omit unused source files?

Tags: c++, makefile, build

I have the project structure below.

```
[22:58:45] BasicProject$ tree -l
.
├── Makefile
└── SourceCode
    ├── Controllers
    │   ├── MenuPage.cpp
    │   ├── MenuPage.hpp
    │   └── Unused.cpp
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── main.hpp
    └── Visuals -> ../AnotherProject/SourceCode/Visuals
        ├── Components
        │   └── Text.hpp
        ├── MenuPage.cpp
        └── MenuPage.hpp
```

Inside the `BasicProject/SourceCode/Controllers` folder, there is an unused source file named `Unused.cpp`. It's not referenced by any of the other source files. Is there a way to exclude files like that from the compilation process? The unused files change according to a set of compilation parameters such as target architecture, library selection, etc.

I use the following simplified Makefile to build my project.

```py
PRJ_NAME := BasicProject

### Paths ###
PRJ_ROOT        := ./
PRJ_SOURCE_CODE := ${PRJ_ROOT}/SourceCode
PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR  := ${PRJ_ROOT}/Outputs
PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR := ${PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR}/Objects
INCLUDES        += -I${PRJ_SOURCE_CODE}

### Derived Variables ###
CPP_SRC_FILES   := $(shell find -L $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE) -type f -name "*.cpp"  -print)
CPP_OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/%.cpp,$(PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o, $(CPP_SRC_FILES))

### Targets ###
all: $(CPP_OBJECTS)    
    @g++ -o ${PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR}/${PRJ_NAME}.elf $(CPP_OBJECTS)
    
clean:     
    rm -rf ${PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR}

${PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR}/%.o : $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @g++ $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: IMHO, you should create a variable that contains all the unused files.  Since the variable is not used in building the code, the files won't be processed.  However, they will still be listed for prior knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude specific files from the compilation process in your Makefile. To exclude the "Unused.cpp" file from being compiled, you can modify your Makefile as follows:

```
PRJ_NAME := BasicProject

### Paths ###
PRJ_ROOT        := ./
PRJ_SOURCE_CODE := ${PRJ_ROOT}/SourceCode
PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR  := ${PRJ_ROOT}/Outputs
PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR := ${PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR}/Objects
INCLUDES        += -I${PRJ_SOURCE_CODE}

### Derived Variables ###
CPP_SRC_FILES   := $(shell find -L $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE) -type f -name "*.cpp"  -not -name "Unused.cpp" -print)
CPP_OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/%.cpp,$(PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o, $(CPP_SRC_FILES))

### Targets ###
all: $(CPP_OBJECTS)
    @g++ -o ${PRJ_OUTPUT_DIR}/${PRJ_NAME}.elf $(CPP_OBJECTS)
    
clean:     
    rm -rf ${PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR}

${PRJ_OBJECTS_DIR}/%.o : $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @g++ $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

By modifying the CPP_SRC_FILES line, we use the find command with the -not -name "Unused.cpp" option to exclude the "Unused.cpp" file from the list of source files to be compiled.

Now, when you run make all, the "Unused.cpp" file will be excluded from the compilation process, and the resulting binary will not include it.

if you like this answer please upvote this .
Happy coding :)

Comment: I liked the answer but it's not scalable. Whenever I add new files I might need to change it. The rationale of it is that I'm building the project for different architectures and each might use a different subset of the source files. Anyway, thanks for your time. Happy coding to you too :)

Comment: @Caglayan - If you have different sources for different targets, that sounds like you should have separate directories each target and select the proper directory for each target build. Not try to pick individual files.

Comment: @BoP What about the common ones? Do you suggest me to create a common directory for each pair of architectures?

Comment: Often a large part does not depend on the precise target, so is used everywhere. Collecting them in one place seems like a good idea. And then add a specific (possibly subdirectory) for each particular "system interface".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there's no automated way to omit "unused" source files.  How could the build system understand which source files are used and which are not?  If you can provide an algorithm for making that decision (that doesn't involve actually compiling all the files anyway to see if any of the symbols in them are needed or not!) then maybe we can suggest a way to implement that algorithm.

If not you'll have to hard-code the list of files which are not used.  You can do it like this:

```
UNUSED := $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/UnusedOne.cpp $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/UnusedTwo.cpp

ALL_SRC_FILES := $(shell find -L $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE) -type f -name "*.cpp" -print)
CPP_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out $(UNUSED),$(ALL_SRC_FILES)
```

In the text of your question you say that there are multiple architectures with different requirements, but in your example makefile there is no indication of building for multiple architectures or choosing flags so there's no way for us to show you how to integrate that.  But you can use constructed variable names; for example if you have a variable `ARCH` that contains the architecture to build for you could have something like:

```
ARCH := x86
x86_UNUSED := $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/This_arm64.cpp
arm64_UNUSED := $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE)/That_x86.cpp

ALL_SRC_FILES := $(shell find -L $(PRJ_SOURCE_CODE) -type f -name "*.cpp" -print)
CPP_SRC_FILES := $(filter-out $($(ARCH)_UNUSED),$(ALL_SRC_FILES)
```